# how to initiate wifi direct pairing using NFC

Tags: android

my goal is to connect two or more devices via wifi direct. i only want to connect them i dont need any protocol to move data or anything. just the process of finding other devices that have my app and connect when tab together using NFC.

thanks in advance.